# Extracting data from a histogram with custom bins in Python

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, histogram, binning

I have a data set of distances between two particles, and I want to bin these data in custom bins. For example, I want to see how many distance values lay in the interval from 1 to 2 micrometers, and so on. I wrote a code about it, and it seems to work. This is my code for this part:

```
#Custom binning of data

bins= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(n,m,figsize = (30,10)) #using this because I actually have 5 histograms, but only posted one here
ax.hist(dist_from_spacer1, bins=bins, edgecolor="k")
ax.set_xlabel('Distance from spacer 1 [µm]')
ax.set_ylabel('counts')
plt.xticks(bins)
plt.show()
```

However, now I wish to extract those data values from the intervals, and store them into lists. I tried to use:

```
np.histogram(dist_from_spacer1, bins=bins)
```

However, this just gives how many data points are on each bin and the bin intervals, just like this:

```
(array([  0,   0,  44, 567, 481, 279, 309, 202, 117,   0]),
 array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]))
```

How can I get the exact data that belong to each histogram bin?

Comment: Well, if you want the values in `dist_from_spacer1` per bin, then you already have them in a compact representation... In your example, the value 3 is found 44, so the bin contains the list of value [3, 3, 3, 3, ..., 3] of size 44. Did I missed something? Do you want the indices instead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `np.histogram` calculates what you need for a histogram, and hence the specific data points are not necessary, just bins' boundaries and count for each bin. However, the bins' boundaries is sufficient to acheive what you want by using [`np.digitizr`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html)

```py
counts, bins = np.histogram(dist_from_spacer1)
indices = np.digitize(dist_from_spacer1, bins)
lists = [[] for _ in range(len(bins))]
[lists[i].append(x) for i, x in zip(indices, dist_from_spacer1)
```

In your case, the bins' boundaries are predefined, so you can use `np.digitize` directly